# How to input n number of elements into an array using scanf()?

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

Is there a way to input `n` of inputs into an array, where `n` is not fixed, using `scanf()`?

```
scanf("%d %d %d %d ... n number of inputs", &array);
```

The problem is that a user enters the size of an array, and the input format is that the inputs are stored using `scanf` in a single line, so it is of the form

```
12 24 36 34 65 24 54 ... upto n inputs
```

So that the first `%d` is stored in `array[0]`, the second into `array[1]`, third into `array[2]`, and all the way upto `array[n-1]`.

It is easy to make a `for` loop for this, but I want to do it in a single line.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in a single line when you already know of an easy way to do it?

Comment: "I want to do it in a single line." Apart from writing your own function to do it, you can't do it in a single line. But then again it wouldn't be a single line if you write a function.

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695237/creating-va-list-dynamically-in-gcc-can-it-be-done and go for vfscanf() ... :-)

Comment: What is the range of `n`?

Answer (score 1):

Not one-liner but still short

```
while(i < n && scanf("%d", &array[i]) == 1)
    i++;
```

You should always check the return value of `scanf` function.
Don't forget to initialize `i` with `0`

Comment: Don't break the line before i++ - and a one-liner it is.